# Problem starting Hadoop service in Program Files

Tags: windows, hadoop, configuration

I have configured Hadoop as follows:

```
user variables: 
   HADOOP_HOME = C:\Progra~1\Hadoop-3.2.0\bin
   JAVA_HOME = C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_201

environment variables:
   C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin
   C:\Progra~1\Hadoop-3.2.0\bin

hadoop-env.cmd:
   set JAVA_HOME=C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_201
```

When I start Hadoop with the command `start-all.cmd` I get this error:

> C:\Program is not recognized internal external command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of space character in `Program Files`. It is better to install java in the root directory for example: `C:\java`

Comment: Yes, I've read this in many answers but I do not like to move the java folder as a solution